# Hello-JNI for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-studio

I just got started with NDK and am struggling to get the Hello-JNI sample running on Android Studio. I got it working using Eclipse but I'd prefer to have it running on Android Studio. I've poured through countless suggestions on how I should put the armeabi folder into a lib folder and pack that inside a jar (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8/Z5yWAvCh4h4J) but so far none of this has worked. It's getting quite frustrating. Does anyone have a working Hello-JNI sample that can be built and run from Android Studio and deployed on a device? I just need a working NDK sample project in Android Studio. Any help is appreciated, thanks guys.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/mpospelov/android-studio-ndk-hello-world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Google, the Android Studio will start supporting NDK projects in it's version 5.0 (I can't find the source but will add it as soon as I get it). At the moment, the latest version is 3.1.

You can find a couple of workarounds on [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/xj51eCWwhFw)

Comment: I have a version from February 18, 2015 and it's marked 1.1.0...

Answer (score 0):

This worked, it's by intel and a little bit dated, but it works.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/using-the-ndk-with-android-studio

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you need Android Ndk, Download it. you need to add android ndk in your project so go to 
windows-->Preference-->Ndk--> and here brows your ndk path.

After that create one android project and right click on project and go to add native support,it's automatically create one .so file.

Just clean and build your project it's include all necessary thing for ndk development.

Now, create nativ method in your activity and generate header file by using javah command corresponding to activity.